# Error: found in Chart.yaml, but missing in charts/ directory: common MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, github, kubernetes, gitlab

Im trying to install Bitnami Mongodb.  When i run the ci/cd pipeline i get the following error:

Error: found in Chart.yaml, but missing in charts/ directory: common

this is what my gitlab-ci.yaml file looks like(package build part):

```
  script:
- kubectl config set-context --current --namespace $NAMESPACE
- export HELM_EXPERIMENTAL_OCI=1 # nodig voor de repo add commands
- export HARBOR_ROBOT_SECRET_DECODED=$(echo -n "$HARBOR_ROBOT_SECRET" | base64 -d)
- helm registry login -u $HARBOR_ROBOT_NAME -p $HARBOR_ROBOT_SECRET_DECODED https://....../
- helm repo add --username $HARBOR_ROBOT_NAME --password $HARBOR_ROBOT_SECRET_DECODED --insecure-skip-tls-verify pgu https://..../chartrepo/pgu
- helm repo update
- helm dependency update
- helm repo add stable https://charts.helm.sh/stable
- helm repo add bitnami https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
- helm search repo bitnami
- >
  helm upgrade --install -f values.yaml --set application.name=mongodb,application.registryServer=$REGISTRY_SERVER,application.image=namespace=$NAMESPACE $HELM_RELEASE_NAME $HELM_CHART --namespace=$NAMESPACE --version=$HELM_CHART_VERSION
```

My chart.yaml file:

```
dependencies:
  - name: common
    repository: https://charts.bitnami.com/bitnami
    tags:
      - bitnami-common
```

UPDATE:
I ran debug:

```
 history.go:56: [debug] getting history for release mongodb
Release "mongodb" does not exist. Installing it now.
install.go:173: [debug] Original chart version: "1.0.0"
install.go:190: [debug] CHART PATH: /root/.cache/helm/repository/mongodb-v1.0.0.tgz
Error: found in Chart.yaml, but missing in charts/ directory: common
helm.go:88: [debug] found in Chart.yaml, but missing in charts/ directory: common
helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/action.CheckDependencies
    helm.sh/helm/v3/pkg/action/install.go:619
main.runInstall
    helm.sh/helm/v3/cmd/helm/install.go:216
main.newUpgradeCmd.func2
    helm.sh/helm/v3/cmd/helm/upgrade.go:115
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).execute
    github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.1.3/command.go:852
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).ExecuteC
    github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.1.3/command.go:960
github.com/spf13/cobra.(*Command).Execute
    github.com/spf13/cobra@v1.1.3/command.go:897
main.main
    helm.sh/helm/v3/cmd/helm/helm.go:87
runtime.main
    runtime/proc.go:225
runtime.goexit
    runtime/asm_amd64.s:1371
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Resolved: Replaced Original chart version: "1.0.0" with package version (to be the same)

install.go:173: [debug] Original chart version: "11.0.6"
install.go:190: [debug] CHART PATH: /root/.cache/helm/repository/mongodb-11.0.6.tgz